# Multiple column value counting ORACLE APEX

Tags: bar-chart, oracle-apex, multiple-columns

Hello to all good people here

I cant seem to get what i need so I wanted to ask for some help here from you guys.

So I have a table

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcoLB.png)

And i need a bar chart counting the values from all 3 columns and summing them together. So I get bar chart represented by y (Matična ploča, ventilator, Probni) and X is a counter of these items from all 3 columns.

I can get it from single column by using Query

```
    select NAZIV_MATERIJALA_1, count(*) value 
 from ALLINAZ_OSIGURANJE ALLINAZ_OSIGURANJE
group by NAZIV_MATERIJALA_1
order by 2 desc
```

Here is what above gets me

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB323.png)

and it's ok for one column, but I need this chart representing the sum of values from all 3 columns named NAZIV_MATERIJALA1 to 3

I truly hope some one can help me make this query.

Thanks to all

Best regards

Marko

Comment: Please consider using a minimal reproducible example of explaining your table and your code. Because of the non-english text, it is hard to answer the question, You should also try to add more tags.

Comment: edited, thanks for the suggestion